# Ajax response shows php text in response page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is my ajax code in view file

```
$('#bidck').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = "ajax=ajax";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/test/check',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```

the code is working fine there is no problem in this, but problem in response side this is my controller side.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class test extends CI_Controller
 {

public function check()
{
    $data = array("data" => "true", "m" => "message");
    Header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
}
```

the problem is when i use **extends CI_Controller** in the controller the output looks is like this [image: error_screen_shot] but without **extends CI_Controller** 
it is OK **{"data":"true","m":"message"}**

Comment: try removing 'Header('Content-Type: application/json');'

Comment: removed Header('Content-Type: application/json'); still it showing

Comment: If you are literally seeing `<?php` in the output code - there's something else going on here...

Comment: is your file starting with `<?php defined('BASEPATH').....` as you post or there is some code before?

Comment: no this is my first line <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Comment: Do you `include()` this file in other PHP script

Comment: remove defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); and try again

Answer (score 0):

Classes extended to use the CI_Controller **must always have the first letter capitalized**.

In your case : you need to change **test** to **Test**, and make sure your file is named the same (**Test.php**)

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Test extends CI_Controller
 {
  public function check()
  {
   $data = array("data" => "true", "m" => "message");
   Header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($data);
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing

> dataType : 'json',

You can add this line after

> data : data,

```
if ($json === false) {
    // Avoid echo of empty string (which is invalid JSON), and
    // JSONify the error message instead:
    $json = json_encode(array("jsonError", json_last_error_msg()));
    if ($json === false) {
        // This should not happen, but we go all the way now:
        $json = '{"jsonError": "unknown"}';
    }
    // Set HTTP response status code to: 500 - Internal Server Error
    http_response_code(500);
}
echo $json;
```

Comment: guys i have check with direct link in browser it too shows like that only so it is not an jquery issues may be some thing on codeinginter side

Comment: okay try this before echo json_encode to show errors
i will add it to the answer it will not show properly here

Comment: Undefined variable: json

Comment: OUTPUT : <?php{"data":"true","m":"message"}